# What is shortcut for change keyboard layout on lubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, input-method

I have installed lubuntu 21.04 on my system. Also, I have added another keyboard layout to enter text in a language other than English-US. Now I need to find with shortcut to use to switch between keyboard layouts. In Ubuntu (and Windows) I used to use super key + space. But this does not work on lubuntu.

Would anyone please guide me?

Comment: I don't use Lubuntu, but a search led me to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185215/fcitx-conflicts-with-default-keyboard-and-mouse-settings-in-lubuntu-lxqt-can) and [this site](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.8/keyboard_and_mouse.html) I hope these will be helpful.

Comment: `fcitx` is the input manager for Lubuntu, and whilst installed, is not enabled by default. I'll refer you to https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.1/fcitx.html as the manual is always a good place to start. Sorry I don't use non-english, but there are questions on our forum, eg. https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-add-chinese-pinyin-input/2107/2 which can be really useful for non-english support.

Comment: I found some solution that worked for me. [In Persian] https://forum.ubuntu.ir/index.php?topic=37672.msg266437#msg266437

Answer (score 0):

First search on menu "keyboard and mouse" or go to preferences,LXQT setting and next keyboard and mouse.
Next go to section keyboard layout and now you can see option for change layout.